# bash script, want to use '$' without it looking for a variable

Tags: bash, variables, environment-variables

I need to write a cron job, to send an mqtt message to `"homie/$HOSTNAME/$state"`.

In the case of $HOSTNAME - it needs to use the env variable, but $state - it must use as is.

How would I add `"homie/$HOSTNAME/$state"` without bash thinking the $state is a variable as well?

Comment: `"homie/$HOSTNAME/"'$state'` -- put the `$state` in single quotes. Or `"homie/$HOSTNAME/\$state"`, keeping it all in double quotes but putting a backslash before the character you want interpreted as literal.

Comment: The 2nd option worked for me in the ansible script I had, tx!